# Transformer: Error importing packages. "ImportError: cannot import name 'SAVE_STATE_WARNING' from 'torch.optim.lr_scheduler'"

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am working on a machine learning project on Google Colab, it seems recently there is an issue when trying to import packages from transformers. The error message says:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'SAVE_STATE_WARNING' from 'torch.optim.lr_scheduler' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py)

The code is simple as follow:

```
!pip install transformers==3.5.1

from transformers import BertTokenizer
```

So far I've tried to install different versions of the transformers, and import some other packages, but it seems importing any package with:

```
from transformers import *Package
```

is not working, and will result in the same error. I wonder if anyone is running into the same issue as well?
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 19):

Change the torch version in colab by running this command

*!pip install torch==1.4.0*. Then, It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Considering you have transformers installed and still its not working.

Go to menu and click

**Runtime -> Restart runtime**

Rerunning script after this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the version of tranformers to the latest one (`4.5.1` at this time). That worked in colab.

```
!pip install transformers
```

Answer (score 2):

The same issue occurred to me with the PyTorch version after being upgraded.
As for the **solution** downgrade Pytorch **version to 1.4.0.**

Use the below command to install

```
!pip install -q torch==1.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch_stable.html
```

It's solved a lot of problems with transformers also.

Answer (score 0):

The above from udara vimukthi worked for me after trying a lot of different things, trying to get the code for "Getting started with Google BERT" to work after cloning the gitHub repository locally, so now ALL of the chapter code works while I'm showing my daughter the models.

Operating system - Windows. Running locally with GPU support, using Anaconda environment.

```
pip install -q --user torch==1.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch_stable.html
```

then I ran into some more issues and had to install the ipwidgets

```
pip install ipywidgets
```

Now it all works, as far as I've gotten. Thanks for the help with the above suggestion it saved me a lot of headaches. :)